# Image doesn't bind to the resource. How to use Relativesource for Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, uri, pack

I am using *Binding* to fill the contents of a `ListView` and also an `Image`. However for some reason the Image doesn't get it's value through binding. 
If I go like

```
<Image Source="/Images/LedGreen.png"/>
```

The image shows up where it should be, however using binding with just substituting the Relative address with a binding argument and handing him the value using a PackUri in the constructor doesn't.

The code is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="DeviceList"
        Source="{Binding Path=DiscoveredDevicesList}">

    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
.
.
.
    <ListView
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Width="500"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="10"
    Grid.Column="1"
    DataContext="{StaticResource DeviceList}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Device name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DeviceName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Rssi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rssi}"/>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="GPS" />
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and the relative property and instructors are:

```
   public Uri ImagePath { get; set; }

   public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ImagePath = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/LedRed.png");
    }
```

I am guessing since I am using `Window.Resources` I am facing this problem. However I want to make sure it's not a silly mistake before I scrub it off and do it the other way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property **`ImagePath`** seems to be located in window's DataContext i.e. **`MainWindowViewModel`**. So, you need to traverse to window's DataContext for binding to work.

Use **`RelativeSource`** to get the window's DataContext:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=DataContext.ImagePath,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: big thanks for the explanation and the solution. It definitely worked. as I mentioned in my question I suspected that it should be the issue, however I never used `Relative` type of addressing before. Great learning. I also got a little question here as well. I did the `Binding for Listview` from a tutorial and the author suggested using `DataContext` for the Listview. I am wondering would it work if I didn't have that part and did binding in a simple way such as `ItemSource="{Binding Path=DiscoveredDeviceList}"`? Is this reference for the `CollectionViewSource` for a specific reason?

Comment: If you want to omit `DataContext`, you have to do this way - `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DiscoveredDeviceList, Source={StaticResource DeviceList}}"`.

Comment: Does it pick up the properties of `DiscoveredDeviceList` in this case in the same fashion such as `<GridViewColumn Header="Device name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DeviceName}"/>` Or I would need to embed the `Source={StaticResource DeviceList}` in each of them?

Answer (score 2):

Here Image data context is `DeviceList`, because you are setting `DeviceList` as date context of list view. But ImagePath
 Is in `MainWindowViewModel`. Since `MainWindowViewModel` is data context in Window you need to refer that data context.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the simple explanation and the code snippet you put in there. Also, good to mention that it didn't work right away until I added Path=`DataContext`.ImagePath. I think I need to read a little bit more about this to find out the purpose of `DataContext` in that piece since I have never used it that way.